# Access left join not working as I am picturing it

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to write a query that involves 3 tables and left joining two of them onto a main one.

```
SELECT UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO, DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2, Card.CardNumberLong AS [Some
Number], Card.Enabled, F_CARD.CARD_NO, F_CARD.END_DT
FROM (((UNIT_MAIN 
INNER JOIN DEPT_MAIN ON UNIT_MAIN.USING_DEPT = DEPT_MAIN.DEPT_ID) 
LEFT JOIN Card ON (UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO = Card.UnitCode AND Card.Enabled = True) )
LEFT JOIN F_CARD ON (UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_ID = F_CARD.ASSIGNED_ID AND (F_CARD.END_DT) Is Null  ))
WHERE  (((UNIT_MAIN.STATUS)="A") AND ((DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2)="AM") AND ((Card.Enabled)=True) ) 
OR (((UNIT_MAIN.STATUS)="D") AND ((DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2)="AM") AND ((Card.Enabled)=True) )
```

The issue I am having is when F_CARD table has rows where the F_CARD.END_DT is not null, causing the main table (unit table) not to show up even though it is a left join and the F_CARD table rows did not satisfy the join condition (or I am to believe).

I don't have any where clauses on the F_CARD table and they are only on the join condition.

*edit*
When I perform

```
LEFT JOIN MFIVE_F_CARD ON (MFIVE_UNIT_DEPT_COMP_MAIN.UNIT_ID = MFIVE_F_CARD.ASSIGNED_ID AND ((MFIVE_F_CARD.END_DT) Is Null)
```

The unit does not appear if the F_CARD table contained rows that had an END_DT, I was to believe that since the left join condition failed, the inner table (unit table) should appear regardless.

If I remove any F_CARD related values from the query, the missing units I am looking for appear. It is an inner join, left join, left join. When the second left join happens, I lose rows even when they should appear.

I narrowed down my joins and just did the inner with the left with F_CARD. Trying to see why it doesnt return rows where the join fails.

Tried to do the following, however im getting an unsupported join error...

```
SELECT 
    UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO
    ,DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2
    ,Card.CardNumberLong AS [SomeNumber]
    ,Card.Enabled
    ,F_CARD.CARD_NO
    ,F_CARD.END_DT FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                UNIT_MAIN 
                INNER JOIN DEPT_MAIN
                ON UNIT_MAIN.USING_DEPT = DEPT_MAIN.DEPT_ID
            ) 
            LEFT JOIN Card
            ON  (UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO = Card.UnitCode AND Card.Enabled = True)
        ) 
        LEFT JOIN F_CARD
        ON (UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_ID = F_CARD.ASSIGNED_ID AND F_CARD.END_DT Is Null)
    ) WHERE 
    (UNIT_MAIN.STATUS = "A" OR UNIT_MAIN.STATUS = "D")
    AND DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2 = "AM"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's because you have clauses in your joins that are doing boolean checks rather than matching records between the tables, i.e.

`Card.Enabled = True` and `(F_CARD.END_DT) IS NULL`

Try changing the query to:

```
SELECT 
    UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO
    ,DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2
    ,Card.CardNumberLong AS [SomeNumber]
    ,Card.Enabled
    ,F_CARD.CARD_NO
    ,F_CARD.END_DT
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                UNIT_MAIN 
                INNER JOIN DEPT_MAIN
                ON UNIT_MAIN.USING_DEPT = DEPT_MAIN.DEPT_ID
            ) 
            LEFT JOIN Card
            ON  UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_NO = Card.UnitCode
        ) 
        LEFT JOIN F_CARD
        ON UNIT_MAIN.UNIT_ID = F_CARD.ASSIGNED_ID
    )
WHERE 
    (UNIT_MAIN.STATUS = "A" OR UNIT_MAIN.STATUS = "D")
    AND DEPT_MAIN.LEV_2 = "AM" 
    AND Card.Enabled = True
```

Comment: The problem here is that Card.Enabled and F_CARD.END_DT IS NULL don't belong in the "Where" condition unless I specify all the possibilties.